# How to send user token to browser when using OpenId connect with Azure AD?

Tags: c#, owin, openid-connect, azure-active-directory

I am connecting AzureAd with OpenId Connect, I am able to connect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/ with my tenantid, client id and perform the authentication using the below configuration

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {

        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,

                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                        code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },

            });
    }
```

My problem is after getting the user token from authorization code i am unable to send it back to the browser. I need to send this token to the browser to perform api calls of the same site or another site registered to the same AD.

I tried to set  cookies of both response and request but it didnt work, i cannot see the cookie values in Action.

Is there a way or events available to utilize the token generated from the above sample.

It would be help full if any one can point me to articles describing OpenId connect with AzureAd and Single Sign on.

Thanks in advance,
Mahesh Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [**OpenId**](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html#ImplicitOK) protocol specifications. I have already used **IdentityServer4** and if I use **Implicit Flow**, it sets `access_token` and `id_token` at **response** URL, like `example.com/api/test#access_token=xxxxxxxx&id_token=xxxxxxxx`. Try to **append** your API response URL in the same way (e.g. using **Redirect**) or add this data to your response as a new `Header`.

Comment: Thanks for the info , I am planning to use Authorization Code Flow.